# What are the best IDE's for express framework - nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

What is the best IDE for express framework?

Comment: You don't really need an IDE, I use VIM personally and it's great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be interested in checking out:

- [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/)
- [Komodo IDE](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide)
- [Nide](http://coreh.github.com/nide/)
- [Cloud9 IDE](http://c9.io/) (web-based)